# JScrollPane doesn't scroll a custom JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a custom JPanel, too large to view into another Jframe. So I inserted the custom JPanel in a JScrollPane into main JFrame but JScrollPane doesn't scroll. Here the code of scroll:

```
    JScrollPane scroll= new JScrollPane(custom_panel,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1076, 555));
    scroll.setBorder(null);
    scroll.setViewportBorder(null);
    scroll.setBounds(10, 256, 1076, 306);
    contentPane.add(scroll);
```

And here the code of custom_panel:

```
    public Custom_Panel() {
    setBorder(null);
    setLayout(null);
    setBounds(100,100,1076, 555);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 1076, 555);
    add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane();
    scroll1.setBounds(10, 34, 1028, 141);
    panel.add(scroll1);

    JList list1 = new JList();
    scroll1.setViewportView(list1);

    JScrollPane scroll2 = new JScrollPane();
    scroll2.setBounds(10, 219, 1028, 144);
    panel.add(scroll2);

    JList list2 = new JList();
    scroll2.setViewportView(list2);

    JScrollPane scroll3 = new JScrollPane();
    scroll3.setBounds(10, 400, 1028, 144);
    panel.add(scroll3);

    JList list3 = new JList();
    scroll3.setViewportView(list3);
```

Comment: Hi Tobias. It would be better if your question contained an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) a.k.a. a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example. That would be easier for us to help you out. What I can tell you is that with null layouts, you'll eventually run into problems with certain display settings. Plus it's too cumbersome to program that way. It would be good for you to investigate how [Java layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) work.

Comment: To have your custom panel contain three identically sized JLists, you should replace `setLayout(null);` with `setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));`, then remove all your setBounds calls. You can even remove the setBounds for the custom panel itself, if you [set a prototype value](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue%28E%29) on each JList. You may also want to set each JList’s [visible row count](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29).

Comment: Thanks @VRG, I had inserted GridLayout as you said and now JScollPane scrolls!